# KL divergence between discrete data and model (choosing hyperprior over Dirichlet concentration parameter $\alpha$)

Tags: estimation, prior, entropy, dirichlet-distribution, kullback-leibler

I have some categorical data that follow an unknown true multinomial distribution $p$ and a model with known multinomial distribution $q$.

I want to estimate the KL divergence between $p$ and $q$ from the data:
$$
\text{KL}(p||q) = - H(p) + H(p,q) 
$$
where the first term is the entropy of the data and the second term the cross-entropy (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence)).

- $-H(p) = \mathbb{E}_p[\log p]$ is nonlinear in $p$, which causes trouble for naive estimators such as the plug-in estimator which can be massively biased. A good estimator for the entropy of the data is represented by the Nemenman-Shafee-Bialek (NSB) estimator. See [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0108025) for the original paper, and [this post](http://www.nowozin.net/sebastian/blog/estimating-discrete-entropy-part-3.html) from Sebastian Nowozin's blog for a gentler introduction.
  In short, a Bayesian estimator with a Dirichlet prior with fixed $\alpha$ (including $\alpha = 0$) is a bad idea for estimating the entropy, because the ``seemingly innocent'' prior completely dominates the posterior over the entropy. Instead, NSB uses a mixture-of-Dirichlet prior with a specific hyperprior $p_\text{NSB}(\alpha)$ on the concentration parameter that induces a relatively flat prior on the entropy.
- On the contrary, $H(p,q) = -\mathbb{E}_p[\log q]$ is linear in $p$ so we could use the plug-in or ML estimator for $\hat{p}$ (i.e., $p_\text{ML}(\alpha) \equiv \delta(\alpha)$), which is unbiased. Incidentally, this choice simplifies the computations a lot since it turns out that $H(p,q)$ is simply the (minus) log likelihood of the model (plus stuff).

Now, if I were to *separately* estimate of the two terms, I would use two distinct priors for $p$, $p_\text{NSB}(\alpha)$ for the entropy and $p_\text{ML}(\alpha)$ for the cross-entropy.

My problem is, how to deal with it when they are part of the same expression?

- Is it okay to be inconsistent in the choice of prior?
- Which prior should I use otherwise between the two? (I would lean towards NSB)
- Or, is there a *third* estimator with yet another prior over $\alpha$ built specifically for this case?

Comment: It seems to me that trying to estimate $KL(p,q)$ when p is unknown is overall pretty useless: are you sure that this is really a quantity you want to estimate? My worry is that any method you use for estimation, bayesian or not, will have massive biases. However, if you really need to, my guess is that you should treat this as a purely frequentist problem: you have constructed two methods you are satisfied with to estimate each half of the sum. Just use the sum of the two methods to estimate the sum.

Comment: @GuillaumeDehaene Thanks for your answer. Well, your first sentence kind of kills about an entire field. I agree that one needs to be careful and it's not a trivial problem, but there are (surprisingly) ways to manage, unless of course one is in some badly undersampled case. For small $K$ (number of categories), I don't see why, given enough samples, we shouldn't at least _attempt_ it. See for example [this paper](http://www.cns.nyu.edu/malab/static/files/publications/2016%20Shen%20Ma.pdf) for an interesting usage (disclosure: I work with one of the authors).